# XPATH get all nodes between text_1 and text_2

Tags: xpath

I have HTML like this

```
<div>
text1
<a>link_1</a>
<a>link_2</a>
text2
<a>link_3</a>
text3
</div>
```

I want to get all the nodes between `text1` and `text2`. The problem is there is no `p` or `span` tag. There are only plain text with content is `text1` and `text2`.

How could I do this with XPATH?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this way :

```
/div/*
    [
        preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) = 'text1'] 
            and 
        following-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) = 'text2']
    ]
```

Comment: fixed the answer :) try it out

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. So we have to remove trailing space :)

Comment: If you want to select text nodes also,, for example if you wanted all between "text1" and "text3", you'd have to replace the `/div/*` part with `/div/node()`

Comment: Yeah, in my case I only want to get the `href` attribute inside `a` tag. I use //div/a[...]