# Parsing sections delimited by tags

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to bin elements that are delimited by headers. I'm struggling with formulating an xpath expression or simple parser that can group my items into sections given by heading tag.

I understand how to scrape lists where the the elements are on the same level or the element level is given by a container, but I'm struggling to figure out how to parse data where the containers are delimited by elements. For example:

```
<div>
<h1>section a</h1>
<item>221</item>
<item>453</item>
<item>473</item>
<h1>section b</h1>
<item>430</item>
<item>493</item>
<h1>section c</h1>
<item>694</item>
<item>931</item>
</div>
```

Is there some paradigmatic way to note the structure using xpath? Is there a way to iterate over scrapy selectors so that I see a dom view and detect the start and stop of these sections?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088066/how-to-scrape-table-with-different-xpath-on-the-same-level-with-scrapy/25095113#25095113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using XPath is to count preceding `h1` siblings of nodes under the `div`, nodes that themselves are not `h1`

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""
<div>
<h1>section a</h1>
<item>221</item>
<item>453</item>
<item>473</item>
<h1>section b</h1>
<item>430</item>
<item>493</item>
<h1>section c</h1>
<item>694</item>
<item>931</item>
</div>""")

In [3]: for i, header in enumerate(selector.xpath('.//div/h1'), start=1):
    print header.xpath('normalize-space()').extract()
    between = selector.xpath(""".//div/node()[count(preceding-sibling::h1)=%d]
                                             [not(self::h1)]""" % i)
    print between.extract()
   ...:     
[u'section a']
[u'\n', u'<item>221</item>', u'\n', u'<item>453</item>', u'\n', u'<item>473</item>', u'\n']
[u'section b']
[u'\n', u'<item>430</item>', u'\n', u'<item>493</item>', u'\n']
[u'section c']
[u'\n', u'<item>694</item>', u'\n', u'<item>931</item>', u'\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var header = null
var items = []

for each element in div
    if element is header
        process previous header, items
        header = the element text
        items = []
    else
        items append element text
end
process last header, items
```